# Can you get the allocated memory for a texture in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, textures, allocation

Assume you have successfully initialized and used a texture, is there a way to inspect how much VRAM memory it is occupying by querying OpenGL directly? perhaps a call to `glIntegerv()` with the correct enumerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unextended OpenGL has no mechanism for *anything* dealing with quantities of memory. Not asking how much memory exists, not asking how much is being used, nothing.

There are some extensions that do this ([ATI_meminfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ATI/ATI_meminfo.txt), [NVX_gpu_memory_info](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NVX/NVX_gpu_memory_info.txt), etc), but these will usually be vendor specific.